# Python remove multiple line

Tags: python, regex, file-io

My file has something like this

```
@email = "abc";

%area = (
    "abc" => 10,
    "xyz" => 10,
);
```

Is there any regex match I can use to match begin with `%area = (` and read the nextline until `);` is found. This is so that I can remove those lines from the file.

Regex that I tried `^%area = \(.*|\n\)` somehow does not continue to match is next line.

So my final file will only have

```
@email = "abc";
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a file `file` contains:

```
@email = "abc";

%area = (
    "abc" => 10,
    "xyz" => 10,
);
```

Would you please try the following:

```
import re
with open("file") as f:
    s = f.read()
    print(re.sub(r'^%area =.*?\);', '', s, flags=(re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)))
```

Output:

```
@email = "abc";
```

If you want to clean-up the remaining empty lines, please try instead:

```
    print(re.sub(r'\n*^%area =.*?\);\n*', '\n', s, flags=(re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE))
```

Then the result looks like:

```
@email = "abc";
```

- The `re.DOTALL` flag makes `.` match any character including a newline.
- The `re.MULTILINE` flag allows `^` and `$` to match, respectively,
  just after and just before newlines within the string.

**[EDIT]**

If you want to overwrite the original file, please try:

```
import re
with open("file") as f:
    s = f.read()
with open("file", "w") as f:
    f.write(re.sub(r'\n*^%area =.*?\);\n*', '\n', s, flags=(re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)))
```

Comment: Yes this works to remove those lines. Is there any trick that I can use to overwrite the file? Should i open as ```r``` then ```w``` or can i use the ```append``` mode? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. To overwrite the file, open the file in "w" mode after reading the original file. The `with` statement automatically closes the opened file and we can safely replace the file. I've updated my answer with the modified script.

Comment: I tried your solution but in linux there's error saying ```[Incomplete last line]``` may I know what is the issue with this?

Comment: I'm sorry actually that issue is caused by another line. Haha Your solution works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I found my previous code removes the newlines around too greedily. I have fixed it now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

To capture and remove your area group, you can use; [link](https://regex101.com/r/K1Wk0O/2)

```
re.sub('%area = \((.|\n)*\);', '', string)
#'@email = "abc";\n\n'
```

However, this will include two new lines after your `@email` line. You could add `\n\n` to the regex to capture that as well;

```
re.sub('\n\n%area = \((.|\n)*\);', '', string)
#'@email = "abc";'
```

However, if the email always follows the same logic, you would be best searching for that line only. [link](https://regex101.com/r/K1Wk0O/1)

```
re.search('(@email = ).*(?=\n)', string).group()
#'@email = "abc";'
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I haven't tested it yet. The one provided by @tshiono works for me. Appreciate your help!